# Moving around between <nav>, <section> and <main>

Tags: css, target, wireframe

I am able to divide the whole page into 4 regions and they are:-

**[header]** (on the very top), **[nav]** (right below the header), **[section**] (on the bottom left) and **[main]** (on the bottom right).

In the **[nav]** portion, I have a list of hyperlinked items (like “item-A”, “item-B”, etc).

The task is to:-

When “item-A” is selected, the corresponding sub-list containing “A1”, “A2”, “A3” etc should be displayed on the **[section]** part. Similarly, if “item-B” is selected, the sub-list “B1”, “B2” should also be displayed on the **[section]** part (overwriting the previous content, of course).

“B2” again is hyperlinked to the file “B.html” which, when called, should be executed on the **[main]** portion.

How can I do all of the above?

P.S. I can finish the above if I use **[frame]** and **[frameset]**. Unfortunately, these become obsolete in HTML5.

[image]

The widths and heights of each region can be defined inside the CSS setup.

Comment: I think in a more complex view like this, a diagram/wireframe might be helpful to include to visually describe what you're wanting. My first instinct would be to use ```document.getElementById("item-A").onclick``` in JavaScript to accomplish this, but I'd need a visual to make sure.

Comment: @Dcfunkster I have uploaded a rough scratch of the wireframe. Can you elaborate a bit more on the coding in html?

Comment: @Mick, you want to have the Section and the Nav all the time irrespective of the HTML page which is loaded right?

Comment: @lokprakash Yes. The [section] should show the latest (current) display before/after the click. The items in [nav] are always ON.

Comment: which framework are you using? in react it can be solve with help of children props.
or create different html pages change the route on clicking on nav and sidebar links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Stack Blitz code:*
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uwbmw4?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.html

---

Because it needs a1,a2,b1,b2 HTML files and stuffs **it does not work here(below)(other parts work other than iframe stuff)** *please try above stackblitz for testing*

```js
const itemAOptions = [
  {
    name: 'A1',
    data: 'A1.html',
  },
  {
    name: 'A2',
    data: 'A2.html',
  },
];

const itemBOptions = [
  {
    name: 'B1',
    data: 'B1.html',
  },
  {
    name: 'B2',
    data: 'B2.html',
  },
];

const dataContainer = document.querySelector('#display');
const menuContainer = document.querySelector('#menu');
const navContainer = document.querySelector('#navBar');

navContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ('nochange' in e.target.dataset) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const toLoad = e.target.dataset.nochange;
    let data = '';
    if (toLoad === 'loadA') {
      data = constructData(itemAOptions);
    } else {
      data = constructData(itemBOptions);
    }
    menuContainer.innerHTML = data;
    display.innerHTML = ``;//emptydata means clear or empty screen as you requested
  }
});

menuContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();

  e.preventDefault();
  const toLoad = e.target;
  let data = '';

  data = `<iframe src="https://web-platform-uwbmw4.stackblitz.io/${toLoad.innerHTML}.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
      </iframe>`;//use src="Your.Website.address.or.directory/${toLoad.innerHTML}.html"

  console.log(toLoad.innerHTML);
  display.innerHTML = data;
});

function constructData(item) {
  let innerData = '';
  item.forEach((i) => {
    innerData += `<li class="li"><a href=# class="a">${i.name}</a></li>`;
  });
  return `<ul class="ul">${innerData}</ul>`;
}

function constructDataIframe(item) {
  let innerData = '';
  item.forEach((i) => {
    innerData += `<iframe src="https://web-platform-uwbmw4.stackblitz.io/${i.data}" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>`;
  });
  return `${innerData}`;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align:center;
}
#navBar{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.lk{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.uli{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.lik{
  list-style: none;
  padding-right:15px;
}
.a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.li{
  list-style: none;

}
.ul{
  float:left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#secHolder{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#display{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
#Holder{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Header</h1>
  <nav id="navBar">
  
  <ul>
    <div class="uli">
    <li class="lik"><a href="#" data-nochange="loadA" class="lk">Item A</a></li>
    <li class="lik"><a href="#" data-nochange="loadB" class="lk">Item B</a></li>
  </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="Holder">

<div id="secHolder">
<h3>Section</h3>
<section id="menu"></section>
</div>
<main id="display"></main>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

> P.S I have tried my best on answering but I don't have regular practice on commenting please try to understand, ask for doubts.

> I cannot understand what you mean by `I cannot use frame its obsolete in html5`, I have used `iframe` is it ok?

Comment: [iframe] is ok but [frame] and [frameset] are obsolete in HTML5 according to what I have learnt from W3C school.

Comment: I have one sugguestion:  After running, at some stage, when I have selected item A and then A1, the main screen shows A.html is running. Everything runs fine. Next, if I  select item B and then B1, the main screen should then be c;leared awaiting for further selection from the sub-menu.

Comment: I can't understand .->Select A->Select A1->Show A1 in main->Select B->Select B1->Show B1 in main.This is what it does.Where is this `sub-menu`?

Comment: The sequence should be:- Select A->Select A1-(from the A's sub-menu)>Run A1.html in main->Select B->**[blanking the main (to make room for the next .html to be shown)]** ->Select B1 (from the B's sub-menu)->Run B1.htnl  in main.

Comment: @Mick Added that ability too!, try it!

Comment: The demo site is taking long time to load.

Comment: the demo is not working until i open the host-sorry please try the code site itself in code site go to preview

Comment: Maybe you shuld delete that link or at least add some comment (warning) next to it.

Comment: done that! try it!

Comment: Hi. Sorry 4 the late reply because I am still learning the stuff. Trying to implement ur code (in DW) and having trouble. 1) Err in ‘const dataContainer = document.querySelector(‘#display’);’ because ‘dataContainer’ is assigned a value but never used. 2) Err in ‘display.innerHTML = ‘ ’;’ because of mixed spaces and tabs together with ‘display’ is not defined. What r those symbols after the equal sign? They dont look like single quotes. 3) Err in ‘consolelog(toLoad.innerHTML);’ because of unexpected console statement. The line that follows also has an error saying ‘display’ is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

You can use buttons instead of a hyperlink and get the same output.

Below is my solution:

```js
const displayItemA = () => {
    document.getElementById("item-A").style.display = 'grid';
    document.getElementById("item-B").style.display = 'none';
}
const displayItemB = () => {
    document.getElementById("item-B").style.display = 'grid';
    document.getElementById("item-A").style.display = 'none';
}

const mainContent = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"];
const displayMain = (q) => {
    document.getElementById(q).style.display = "grid";
    const toNone = mainContent.filter(e => e !== q);
    for (let i = 0; i < toNone.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(toNone[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
}

const displayA1 = () => displayMain("A1");
const displayA2 = () => displayMain("A2");
const displayA3 = () => displayMain("A3");
const displayB1 = () => displayMain("B1");
const displayB2 = () => displayMain("B2");
const displayB3 = () => displayMain("B3");
```

```css
:root {
--main-color:red;
--dark-color:#444;
}
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
margin: 0px;
display: grid;
place-items: center;
font-size: 20px;
}

/* repeated element */
.button-nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--main-color);
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: start;
}

.header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--dark-color);
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--dark-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1em;
}
.nav h2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}

.section {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 175px);
    width: 30%;
    border-right: 2px solid var(--dark-color);
    padding: 30px;
    gap: 1em;
}
.sub-nav {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1em;
}
#item-A, #item-B{ display:none }

.main {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 175px);
    width: 70%;
    display: grid;
    padding: 30px;
    gap: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
#A1 { display: grid; }
#A2, #A3, #B1, #B2, #B3 { display: none; }
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">
        <h2>Nav</h2>
        <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayItemA()">item-A</button>
        <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayItemB()">item-B</button>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <section class="section">
            <h3>Section</h3>
            <br />
            <nav class="sub-nav" id="item-A">
                <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayA1()">A1</button>
                <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayA2()">A2</button>
                <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayA3()">A3</button>
            </nav>
            <nav class="sub-nav" id="item-B">
                <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayB1()">B1</button>
                <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayB2()">B2</button>
                <button class="button-nav" onclick="displayB3()">B3</button>
            </nav>
        </section>
        <main class="main">
            <h3>Main</h3>
            <div id="A1">These are the contents of A1.</div>
            <div id="A2">These are the contents of A2.</div>
            <div id="A3">These are the contents of A3.</div>
            <div id="B1">These are the contents of B1.</div>
            <div id="B2">These are the contents of B2.</div>
            <div id="B3">These are the contents of B3.</div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

You can also test the code at [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/SaadShaikhCodepen/pen/dyVmKap) so you can see it on a larger viewport.

**Update:** I made the items in the "section" area blank by default as per the OP's request. This was done by changing the value of the display of "#item-A" to "none" in the CSS file.

Comment: It is almost exactly what I want. I am wondering is it possible that the initial setup of the [section]  screen is blank when none of the items in [nav] is selected.

Comment: @Mick definitely. I just made the changes.

Comment: But if I  use buttons, I need to make some changes in my originial. Upvoted.

Comment: @Mick let me know if you need any assistance with that. All the best.

Comment: I will. Appreciate your help. Thanks again for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't concentrate on stylings. It is recommended to use iframe instead of object tag. You can try exploring that as well.

```js
const itemAOptions = [{
  name:"A1",
  data:"A1.html"
}, {
  name:"A2",
  data:"A2.html"
}];

const itemBOptions = [{
  name:"B1",
  data:"B1.html"
}, {
  name:"B2",
  data:"B2.html"
}];

const dataContainer = document.querySelector("#display");
const menuContainer = document.querySelector("#menu");
const navContainer = document.querySelector("#navBar");

navContainer.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  e.stopPropagation();
  if("nochange" in e.target.dataset){
    e.preventDefault();
    const toLoad = e.target.dataset.nochange;
    let data = '';
    if(toLoad === "loadA"){
      data = constructData(itemAOptions);
    }
    else{
      data = constructData(itemBOptions);
    }
    menuContainer.innerHTML = data;
  }
});

menuContainer.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  e.stopPropagation();
  if("spaload" in e.target.dataset){
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = e.target.dataset.spaload;
    dataContainer.innerHTML=`<object type="text/html" data=${data} ></object>`;
  }
});

function constructData(item){
  let innerData = '';
  item.forEach((i)=>{
    innerData+=`<li><a href=${i.data} data-spaload=${i.data}>${i.name}</a></li>`;
  });
  return `<ul>${innerData}</ul>`;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-nochange="loadA">Item a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-nochange="loadB">Item B</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<h3>Section</h3>
<section id="menu"></section>
<main id="display"></main>
```

Comment: [iframe] is another item I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const embed = document.getElementById("main-frame");
const navLinksContainer = document.getElementById("nav-links");
const subLinksContainer = document.getElementById("sub-links");

const pageLinks = {
  "item-A": {
    A1: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia",
    A2: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria",
    A3: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America",
  },
  "item-B": {
    B1: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbados",
    B2: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahamas",
    B3: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil",
  },
  "item-C": {
    C1: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada",
    C2: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayman_Islands",
    C3: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chile",
  },
};

// Creates the page link element
function createPageLink(text, href = "") {
  const listItem = document.createElement("LI");
  const anchor = document.createElement("A");
  anchor.innerHTML = text;
  anchor.href = href;
  listItem.appendChild(anchor);
  listItem.anchor = anchor;
  return listItem;
}

window.onload = function loadHandler() {
  // build all the sub links for each nav link.
  Object.keys(pageLinks).forEach((text) => {
    const subSectionLinks = Object.keys(pageLinks[text]).map((subText) => {
      const subLink = createPageLink(subText, pageLinks[text][subText]);
      subLink.anchor.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        embed.src = event.target.href;
      });
      return subLink;
    });

    // replaces the sub links in the left section
    // for each corresponding nav link that's clicked.
    const navLink = createPageLink(text);
    navLink.anchor.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      subLinksContainer.innerHTML = "";
      subSectionLinks.forEach((element) =>
        subLinksContainer.appendChild(element)
      );
      embed.src = "";
    });
    navLinksContainer.appendChild(navLink);
  });
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 28px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #920000;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #222;
}

.page {
  width: 702px;
  height: 918px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h"
    "h h h h"
    "n n n n"
    "s m m m"
    "s m m m"
    "s m m m"
    "s m m m"
    "s m m m"
    "s m m m"
    "s m m m";
}

.page > * {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.page > header {
  grid-area: h;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.page > nav {
  grid-area: n;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.page > section {
  grid-area: s;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.page > main {
  grid-area: m;
  text-align: center;
}

.page > nav div {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.page > nav ul {
  width: calc(100% - 25%);
  text-align: center;
}

.page > nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.page > nav ul li:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.page > section ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 40px;
}

.page > section ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.page > main p {
  height: 8%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.page > main iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(92% - 20px);
  border: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header>Header</header>

  <nav>
    <div>nav</div>
    <ul id="nav-links"></ul>
  </nav>

  <section>
    section
    <ul id="sub-links"></ul>
  </section>

  <main>
    <p>main</p>
    <iframe allowTransparency="true" id="main-frame"></iframe>
  </main>
</div>
```

### Update:

I added a line of code to clear the `iframe` whenever the user selects a different link from the navigation bar as per the comments made by the OP.

Comment: [iframe] is another item I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Mick In another comment you said, "[iframe] is ok..." May I ask what would be a preferable alternative?

Comment: I mean using [iframe] can do the job but [iframe] is just opening a new window whose size is exactly that of the [main] and that window is right on top of the [main]. It would be  better, I think, if *.html can be executed directly in [main]. Sorry for the mislead of my wording.

Comment: @Mick is there a reason why it would be better for `*.html` to render directly in `main` as opposed to a nested `iframe`? do you want me to try with a shadow-DOM?